# Allow upload if server side encryption is AES256 gives me access denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I was trying to create a policy in which I am having a condition to allow upload if "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": "AES256".

[image: Policy Generated]

The generated policy is

```
{
  "Id": "Policy1558792743511",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1558792083035",
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::thebucketofsudhanshu/*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": "AES256"
        }
      },
      "Principal": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

When I put it in my bucket policy and saved it. It says "Access Denied".

While when I changed the policy to deny

```
"Effect": "Deny",
"Condition": {
        "StringNotEquals": {
          "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": "AES256"
        }
     }
```

It gets saved.

I am confused.

Block all public access is ON.

Can anyone please clarify.

Comment: `"Principal": "*"` is public access, allowing anyone, anywhere, to upload to your bucket.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot okay. but why am I getting access denied when "Effect": "Allow" and "StringEquals" condition is there?

Comment: Because creating that policy would grant public access, and as you said, *"Block all public access is ON."*